# Only keep rows within certain field based on another field

Tags: sql, oracle, join, exists

Having trouble with this one, can this be done in one query? Or should I delete all the N records and then use another query to get what I need? Help is appreciated!!

Only keep rows belonging to a group_id where the group_id contains YY for the same brand. If the flag is a Y/N or N/N for the same brand within a group_id, then remove those records.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please supply your data so that we can copy-paste it into an example and work with it. You would have saved me at least 15 min ....

I did not bother with unimportant data - they will be different from your input, but don't matter.

One way ist to use an OLAP function partitioned by `grp_id,brand,flag`, and a counter, and filtering by flag and counter value 2, or you could also use a grouping query, and join that grouping query back to the base table.

Here is the OLAP solution:

```
WITH
-- your (simplified) input, don't use in query )
indata(grp_id,secondary_id,account_id,site_id,op_id,brand,flag) AS (
          SELECT 1, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'toyota', 'N' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'toyota', 'N' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'tesla' , 'Y' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'tesla' , 'Y' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'toyota', 'Y' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'toyota', 'N' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'tesla' , 'Y' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'tesla' , 'N' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'toyota', 'Y' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'toyota', 'N' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'tesla' , 'Y' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'tesla' , 'N' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'toyota', 'Y' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'toyota', 'Y' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'tesla' , 'N' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 1055884386, 123, 'usa', 2,'tesla' , 'N' FROM dual
)
-- end of your input; replace following comma with "WITH" ...                                                                                                                                                                              
,
w_counter AS (
  SELECT
    *   
  , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY grp_id,brand,flag) AS occ_count
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  *
FROM w_counter
WHERE flag='Y'
  AND occ_count = 2 
;
-- out  grp_id | secondary_id | account_id | site_id | op_id | brand  | flag | occ_count 
-- out --------+--------------+------------+---------+-------+--------+------+-----------
-- out       1 |   1055884386 |        123 | usa     |     2 | tesla  | Y    |         2
-- out       1 |   1055884386 |        123 | usa     |     2 | tesla  | Y    |         2
-- out       4 |   1055884386 |        123 | usa     |     2 | toyota | Y    |         2
-- out       4 |   1055884386 |        123 | usa     |     2 | toyota | Y    |         2
```

And, for good measure, also the grouping solution - not repeating the input WITH clause ...

```
grp AS (
  SELECT
    grp_id
  , brand
  FROM indata
  WHERE flag='Y'
  GROUP BY
      grp_id
    , brand
  HAVING COUNT(brand) = 2
)
SELECT
  i.*
FROM indata i
JOIN grp  USING(grp_id,brand)
ORDER BY grp_id
;
-- out  grp_id | secondary_id | account_id | site_id | op_id | brand  | flag 
-- out --------+--------------+------------+---------+-------+--------+------
-- out       1 |   1055884386 |        123 | usa     |     2 | tesla  | Y
-- out       1 |   1055884386 |        123 | usa     |     2 | tesla  | Y
-- out       4 |   1055884386 |        123 | usa     |     2 | toyota | Y
-- out       4 |   1055884386 |        123 | usa     |     2 | toyota | Y
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this, good to know about posting the data. Not sure how I didn't even think about that. Got some issues though when there happens to be the following added to the data. I removed the secondary_id and op_id from the data. I need the grp_id 1 below to stay and the grp_id 2 to be removed. SInce your answer hardcodes it at 2, the grp_id 2 comes back. 

1 456 can honda Y ---

1 456 can honda Y ---

1 456 can honda Y ---

2 456 can honda Y ---

2 456 can honda N ---

2 456 can honda Y ---

Comment: the group id (`grp_id`) of 2 was in your original input. Shall I try with `gap_id` of 1, and account id of 456, `site_id` of 'can', and `brand` of 'honda'?